# Show captured picture when activity opened again

Tags: android, image, camera, onresume

I have an activity that calls the camera intent to capture a picture and assign it as a profile picture. The activity works fine except that when I click back and then open the activity again the picture is not displayed anymore.

How can I make it show everytime the user opens this activity? Here's my code for that activity

```
public class MyAccountActivity extends Activity {

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private TextView name;
private TextView userId;
private TextView address;
private TextView email;
private TextView phone;
private ImageButton profilePicture;
private Bitmap bm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);
    setUpViews();
Log.v("test","this is test: "+LoginActivity.user.getName());
}

private void setUpViews() {
    //setting up views

    //calling user details from User [] instance 

}

public void ViewPicture(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(
    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPath()); 
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bm);
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bm, null, null);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();  
}
```

I have tried to call `profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bm)` `onResume()` but my app crashes. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: try calling setupViews from onResume. You setup everything when you create the activity, but the activity isn't recreated when you come back to it, so I don't think the image is getting applied. what crash are you getting when you try to set the image?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply...ill test your suggestion right away and ill post a response. Regards

Comment: @toadzky It didnt change anything. I think because I set profilePicture when getting result back from the intent. I was thinking if i can load the picture from its saved location from the phone? is that possible? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the captured image with some uri path

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.fromFile(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)), imageName.png);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri));
```

then whenever you want to display the image, use this uri

```
profilePicture.setImageUri(uri)
```

Comment: The above code goes when calling the camera intent right? So basically in my ViewPicture() ?

Comment: it seems that this suggestion is the correct solution but unfortunately I cannot implement it properly. 
Regards

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661424/how-to-capture-the-image-and-save-it-in-sd-card) Another Solution.

Comment: hope you understood how to do it now, the link also gives the same solution